# Looping through a list that contains dicts and displaying it a certain way

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

These are 3 dicts I made each with the 4 same keys but of course different values.

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}
```

I stored the dicts in a list.

```
students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
```

What I'd like to do is loop through the list and display each like so:

```
"""
student's Name: val
student's Homework: val
student's Quizzes: val
student's Tests: val
"""
```

I was thinking a for loop would do the trick `for student in students:` and I could store each in a empty dict `current = {}` but after that is where I get lost. I was going to use **getitem** but I didn't think that would work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those dictionaries are basically a poor man's class.  If you're familiar with Python's classes and object-oriented programming, you could create a `Student` class with a `transcript` method (or just override the `__str__` magic method).  You'd then just print `student.transcript()` or `str(student)` in a `for student in students:` loop.  (If the next function or program that will handle that data expects a `dict` though, leave the data in a `dict`.)

Comment: ChrisSlightGhost do keys print order is important for you ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this:

```
students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

def print_student(student):
    print("""
        Student's name: {name}
        Student's homework: {homework}
        Student's quizzes: {quizzes}
        Student's tests: {tests}
    """.format(**student)) # unpack the dictionary

for std in students:
    print_student(std)
```

Comment: Thanks bud I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Use loop below to display all students data **without hardcoding keys**:

```
# ... 
# Defining of lloyd, alice, tyler
# ...

students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
for student in students:
    for key, value in student.items():
        print("Student's {}: {}".format(key, value))
```

**Good Luck !**

Comment: Two points: first, `iteritems` doesn't exist in modern Python anymore, but `items` works in both 2 and 3, so you might as well use it.  Second, while you don't hardcode the keys, this loses the desired output order because dicts are unordered; for me, "name" comes third in the output, which feels weird.

Comment: @DSM Thanks for your suggestions, it's really use full, i've updated `iteritems` to `items`.